# trouble with relative path to javascript file

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to link a js (the js is a local file in the project) to this html (results.html) :

[image]

The problem is that the js is not loading .

I have try with :

```
/static/js/ResultspieChart.js
../static/js/ResultspieChart.js
static/js/ResultspieChart.js
```

But if I use:

```
<script th:src="@{/js/ResultspieChart.js}"></script>
```

it works , [th is a Java template engine](http://www.thymeleaf.org/)

In fact the url according to intelliJ helper is well formed,where is the problem ?

Comment: Are you loading your html with a http-server or from file system?

Answer (score 0):

The file system paths are not resolved correctly most of the times. Use an http server to serve your html and `../static/js/ResultpieChart.js` should work. You can use `http-server` npm package as below (Prerequisite: You should have node installed):
1. Install `http-server` globally

> npm install -g http-server

2. Start the `http-server` in the root of your project

> http-server

This will start a server at default port (8080). So if you browse `localhost:8080`, you can see your files